# Tricky inheritance (Хитрое наследование)

Tags: java

Итак, продолжим экскурс в Java-задачки. Очередная из тех же источников, правда, она может показаться весьма простой для бывалых или для тех, у кого под рукой компилятор.

Код:

```
public class A {
    public A() {
        myMethod();
    }
    public void myMethod() {
        Date date = new Date();
    }
}

public class B extends A {
    private Date date = new Date();

    public B() {
        date = new Date();
    }

    @Override
    public void myMethod() {
        System.out.println(date);
    }

    //...
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B sub = new B();
        sub.myMethod();
    }
}
```

Вопросы:

1. Каков же вывод данной программы?
2. Поясните свой предыдущий ответ

Для изучающих ООП задачка будет весьма полезной. Кроме того, можете добавить свои соображения по поводу того, почему данная программа не является отказоустойчивой (robust).

Comment: Когда собирался отвечать на вопрос, вспомнил, что похожую ситуацию обсуждал Блох в своей книге "Эффективная Java". Заглянул туда - а там практически идентичный пример :) В общем, рекомендую всем программистам, которые уже имеют некоторый опыт работы, книга великолепная.

Comment: Мне кажется, будет нагляднее вместо неопределенных инстансов Date (значения которых зависят от времени выполнения программы) использовать определенные строки: в каждом интересующем нас месте программы - своя строка, значение которой известно до выполнения программы. Тогда будет удобно отвечать на вопрос "какой вывод данной программы?", приводя в качестве ответа строку(и), а не тыкая пальцем в код: программа выведет дату(ы), которая(ые) инстанциируется там-то и там-то.

Comment: Только имея слабое представление о том, как это правильно работает, вы натолкнете на, возможно, НЕ правильную мысль начинающего программера. Оно потому так и называется, что даты с одинаковыми именами определяются и в одном и в другом классе, что может запутать, а значит даст при понимании ситуации больше пользы.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Признаюсь сразу, ответ получен с помощью компилятора.

```
null
Tue Oct 11 00:19:35 MSD 2011
```

Все дело в том, что вызываемый из конструктора A myMethod() оказывается одноименным методом конструктора B, а в это время поле date класса B еще не инициализировано датой. Понятно, что память выделена и обнулена. Вторая строчка вывода это ожидаемый результат вызова sub.myMethod() из main().

Порядок вызовов такой: конструктор A, из него метод myMethod() класса B (он переопределяет myMethod() класса A), конструктор B (инициализирует дату) и наконец sub.myMethod();

Локальный для класса A метод myMethod() вообще не вызывается. Директива @Override в данном случае никак себя не проявляет (сигнатуры одинаковы).

Видимо это пример того, что не надо делать методы с одинаковыми именами (не только сигнатурами !), вызываемыми из конструкторов. Да, Java это язык, на котором элегантно пишутся головоломки.

Comment: Рад, что вам снова понравилось. Но задание экзаменационное, никакого компьютера. Выделено всего 20 минут. Чтобы понять и ответить на три вопроса (письменно). Подожду с принятием, может, кто еще про robust скажет пару слов.

Comment: Надеюсь скажут. Уровень у меня еще не тот, что бы без компьютера, всухую.

Comment: @Dex, это пример того, что я имел в виду. Используя даты, из этого ответа не понятно, **какую именно** дату выводит программа: 1) ту, которая инстанциируется в инициализаторе поля date класса B, 2) которая инстанциируется в конструкторе B, или же 3) которая инстанциируется в методе A#myMethod. Нужно явно указывать это в ответе. Если бы были строки вместо дат, то необходимость в этом отпала бы. Программа дала бы более осмысленный вывод:

null
I'm from constructor of B

Comment: От вас не требовалось написать точную дату и т.п. Вопрос сводится не к этому. 
На экзамене ответ вида:

> null
> Date

был верным. 

Главное затем пояснить, что за чем идет. А еще главнее пояснить, почему программа не является отказоустойчивой, по поводу чего я бы и просил вас высказаться, вместо того, чтобы рассуждать на тему задания, которое я преподношу **as-is**, то-бишь как получил, в том же виде и отдаю.

Comment: Согласен, чего-то я на этих строках зациклился, хых :)

Comment: "Видимо это пример того, что не надо делать методы с одинаковыми именами (не только сигнатурами !), вызываемыми из конструкторов." - нет, это пример того, что может случиться, если вызывать переопределяемый метод из конструктора. Иногда это как раз то, что нужно, но обычно - нет.

Comment: имхо стоит избегать кода:

    public A()
    {
        myMethod();
    }

в пользу factory method (или abstract factory, в зависимости от ситуации):

    public static A createInstance()
    {
        A a = new A();
        a.myMethod(); 
        
        return a;
    }

Answer (score 2):

В дополнение к ответу avp

Инициализация состояния класса путем вызова переопределяемого метода - потенциальная угроза неправильной инициализации родительского класса, и, как следствие, непрогнозируемой работы производного класса.

Кроме того, возможна утечка недоинициализированного экземпляра через this вследствие его передачи другим объектам и/или потокам из переопределяемого метода.

Comment: Не совсем понял фразу *Инициализация состояния класса путем вызова переопределяемого метода*, т.е. переопределить и не вызвать?

Comment: Я имел ввиду, что если метод класса предназначен для его переопределения наследниками, то не стоит его вызывать из конструктора.

А вот фразу "переопределить и не вызвать" уже не понял я.

Comment: Я не до конца понял, вы предлагаете переопределить метод, но не использовать его, или то, что вы сказали.

Comment: Я ничего не предлагаю :) Я лишь указываю на то, что методы, предназначенные для переопределения, небезопасно вызывать из конструктора.

Comment: А я просто уточнил ибо не понял:) Спасибо!